# Can I check that a path contains a value FIrebase RealtimeDatabase Rules

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have rules that look like this

```
"PermanentChatInfo":{
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        
        "$ChatUid":{
          
         ".write": "auth.uid != null && $ChatUid.contains('auth.uid') || !newData.exists()"
          
        }
        
  },
```

Whereas "$ChatUid" is the creators uid concatenated with "!" and a random generated number.

I want to allow a user to be able to write to that path if the $ChatUid contains the users Uid. However when I create a chat in my app, it doesn't write to that path in the Realtime Database. Is there anything i'm doing wrong?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please do not share pictures of code.  Copy the code into the question itself, and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: Will edit my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$ChatUid` is a string, so you should be able to [call `contains`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#containssubstring) on it.

The problem is in:

```
$ChatUid.contains('auth.uid')
```

This checks whether your `$ChatUid` capture/variable contains the literal string `auth.uid`.

What you're looking for is `auth.uid` without the quotes:

```
$ChatUid.contains(auth.uid)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. One last question. How long does it take for Firebase rules to apply? Only because I tried it and it didn't write to the database.

Comment: I did upvote and checkmark your answer because it did answer my question.

Comment: Rules apply pretty much within seconds for me. But if you're having problems it might be better to use the rules playground to test if it actually works the way you imagine (I didn't try it myself, but merely spotted a mistake in your implementation of the logic).